# How to play system button click sound on iPad?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I need to play some system sound when users click button in my application which is running on iPad. How to implement it in iOS?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to play a short sound (shorter than 30 sec), you can do it easily like this:

**Note**: You'll have to add AudioToolbox framework and import it (`#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>`)

```
SystemSoundID mySSID;

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"beep" ofType:@"wav"];
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath: path], &mySSID); 

AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(mySSID);
```

Also note that the file can be:

- No longer than 30 seconds in duration
- In linear PCM or IMA4 (IMA/ADPCM) format
- Packaged in a .caf, .aif, or .wav file

Comment: Great!! But is it possible to play some system sound? I don't want to upload anythink new... Somethink like standart iphone button click sound

Comment: I am not sure about that... Though I know for sure that you can use the 'vibrate' _system sound_. If I find something I will let you know.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, you can't access system sounds on the device. I've done some researching though and you can find the clicking sound that apple use in the iPhone simulator. `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework` The file is called `Tock.aiff`. Just add this file to your project.

Comment: @LiamGeorgeBetsworth Cool! I guess he can grab a copy of the file into his bundle then.

Answer (score 3):

You should use AVAudioPlayer.

There's a great tutorial [here](http://mobileorchard.com/easy-audio-playback-with-avaudioplayer/) on using AVAudioPlayer to play sounds. A very simple example of it's use:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/audiofile.mp3",dataPath];

NSError *error;
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];

if (audioPlayer == nil)
    NSLog([error description]);
else
    [audioPlayer play];
```

Comment: Great!! But is it possible to play some system sound? I don't want to upload anythink new... Somethink like standart iphone button click sound

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"gorilla 2" ofType:@"mp3"];
AVAudioPlayer* theAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];

theAudio.delegate=self;
[theAudio play];
```