# xcode5 - playing sound after pushing button is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, xcode5

OBJECTIVE :
I am trying to get a sound to play when a button is clicked. This sound will be preformed by an action called "play". The sound is in my resource folder and is called SoftClick.mp3

PROBLEM:
There is no sound at all being played in either simulator or the real device. The code does not give any errors.

CONNECTIONS:
The button, that needs to give sound, is connected to the action play and is used as a Modal Segue to show another view controller. Both viewcontrollers use the same .h and .m script.

```
CODE FOR .H
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import<AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h>


@interface ViewController : UIViewController

{
  AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;



- (IBAction) play;




@end
```

Action and audioplayer are defined as i thought was necessary (?)

```
THE CODE FOR .M
#import "ViewController.h"
#import<AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h>
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize audioPlayer;


-(IBAction)play

{

    AVAudioPlayer* theAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"SoftClick"ofType:@"mp3"]] error:NULL];

    [theAudio play];

}
```

Can someone please help me with correcting my coding so this could work in xcode5?
Ive spend some hours trying to figure out why this will not work an tried combinations like without segue etc. I do not want to steal the code from someone else and am trying to build this on my own.

Thanks in advanced,

Lien

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to play system button click sound on iPad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10738551/how-to-play-system-button-click-sound-on-ipad)

Comment: This is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue, as I'm assuming you're using ARC, is that you aren't retaining the `AVAudioPlayer` object. You create the object, call play, but then it is instantly released and dealloc'd. You need to add `self.audioPlayer = theAudio;`